# How to split value inside <td> using Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a HTML table which look like this.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Alice</td>
            <td>England</td>
            <td>English<br>Swedish<br>French</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>German</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Third column may contain multiple values, separated by `<br>`.

HTML is generated inside a PHP foreach loop.

I am using jQuery plugin Datatables to make interactive table with dropdown filter for last column.

This is my code for this:

```
initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns([2]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Filter by country</option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(".dataTables_filter") )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                if(d.length) {
                    di = d.replace("<br>", "");
                    select.append('<option value="' + di + '">' + di + '</option>')
                }
            } );
        } );
    }
```

All works fine if third column does not contain multiple values, but if third column contain multiple values the values are concatenate in the dropdown and it cant filter by that/those values.

```
<select>
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Filter by country</option>
    <option value="German">German</option>
    <option value="English Swedish French">English Swedish French</option>
</select>
```

Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this code:

```
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                if(d.length) {
                    di = d.replace("<br>", "");
                    select.append('<option value="' + di + '">' + di + '</option>')
                }
            } );
```

for this code:

```
        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( di, j ) {
            if(di.length) {
                let separator = '\n';
                if(di.text().indexOf(separator)==-1){
                    select.append('<option value="' + di + '">' + di + '</option>');
                } else {
                    let arrValues = di.text().split(separator);
                    for(let ix=0;ix<arrValues.length;ix++){
                        select.append('<option value="' + arrValues[ix] + '">' + arrValues[ix] + '</option>'); 
                    }
                }
            }
        } );
```

The "d" variable is missused as "di" and EDIT: You must define the separator. I fixed the code.

Comment: This is not what i am after. I somehow need to make a single <td> contain multiple values that are all accessible each by them self, as they where in their own row, in the filter dropdown. The seperator can be anything. Just used <br> as example

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
   if(d.length) {
       di = d.replace("<br>", "");
       select.append('<option value="' + di + '">' + di + '</option>')
    }
} );
```

to

```
column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
   var optionArr = d.split("<br>");
   
   optionArr.forEach(function(optName) {                
      var optionExists = ($("#language option[value='"+optName+"']").length > 0);
      if(!optionExists){
         select.append( '<option value="'+optName+'">'+optName+'</option>' );
      }                    
   });
});
```

Also Change: `.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )` to `.search( this.value )`

**OR**

simply use

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myDatatable').dataTable( {
         "sDom": 'W<"clear">lfrtip',
         "oColumnFilterWidgets": {
               "aiExclude": [ 0,1 ],
               "sSeparator": '<br>'
          }
    });
});
```